# API for google reminders created in the calendar

Tags: android, calendar, reminders

For some time we have been getting the option to create reminders using the calendar app in android. I was wondering if there's an API for it - displaying the reminders for starters. I'm not retrieving them using query with "content://com.android.calendar/events" and there's no mention of this in the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Wondering this too, did you find?